# Comparison of stability of cyclic imines

Tags: organic-chemistry, stability

[image]
I am looking for the reason for the lowest stability of cyclohexane-1,3,5-triimine (D).

I was not able to find any explanation using resonance or aromaticity.
All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cyclohexane-1,3,5-triimine tautomer is benzene-1,3,5-triamine, which is aromatic. This makes this trienamine form much more stable than any of the other possible tautomeric forms.

Comment: Not really, this question is pretty much nonsense, as all of them are "unstable", whatever this is supposed to even mean...

Comment: I agree this is clearly a textbook unrealistic question. But my best interpretation was that the condition are such the imines don't solvolyse or anything as such and that the question is about tautomerism (which, I agree, assumes presence of some Lewis bases).

Comment: Your answer is not very clear. Why does that make trienamine the least stable?

Comment: It makes *triimine* the least stable, because it readily tautomerizes to *trienamine*, which is aromatic therefore stable. (I'm guessing that in the context of the original question, stable means not transforming into an enamine)